# Manually find nearest coordinate with Meteor/Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coordinates, distance

I have used the `$near` command to return a list of cities near my coordinates.

```
 Villages.find({loc: {$near: [lat,long], $maxDistance: 2}}, 
                     {fields: {name: 1, _id: 0}}, 
                     {limit: 1}
                     );
```

This works, but I run into issues where you can be near the edge of a large city, but still be technically closer to the center of the next neighbouring city than the one you're in. For this reason I'd like to weight the results against the population (only data I have to guess whether a city is large or not). Since I don't believe I can do this with `$near`, I would need to manually (haversine or otherwise) select for the nearest cities. How would I go about this?

Comment: What is Meteor/Mango? Would you be fine with looking at alternative sources for your data? If so, just do a Google search for the data or ask  the people at OpenData.SE where you can find the city centers.

Comment: Meteor is a javascript framework like Node.js, and MongoDB is a NoSQL style database engine. I'm using the Geonames.org database for my city names and locations. They have population data but the locations are only  coordinates of the center of cities, rather than area shape geometry.

Comment: You can change the maximum distance in the mongo query as per the population i.e) population=20m means maxdistance=2 population =40m means maxdistance=4 like that

Comment: @Vignesh Is there a way to reverse the scale of that so larger populations show up as closer?

Answer (score 1):

If this works then it's good. You have a slight technical error in your code which may be responsible:

```
 Villages.find({loc: {$near: [long,lat], $maxDistance: 2}}, 
                 {fields: {name: 1, _id: 0}}, 
                 {limit: 1}
                 );
```

Mongo uses `long, lat` not `lat, long`. It may be also worth mentioning this pattern is deprecated in favour of:

```
loc: { $near : {
            $geometry : [long, lat],
            $maxDistance : 2
        } }
```

Where `loc` looks something like this:

```
loc: {
    type : "Point",
    coordinates : [ long , lat ]
}
```

Be sure to also index them, too: `MyCollection._ensureIndex({"loc" : "2dsphere"});`

Comment: if i dont add this MyCollection._ensureIndex({"loc" : "2dsphere"});, the whole query doesnt work?